# Why is this python exception not ValueError?

Tags: python

The code:

```
import datetime

TF = "%d-%M-%Y %H:%M"
last= datetime.datetime.strptime( "11/07/10 10:00", TF)
```

Throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strange.py", line 4, in <module>
    last= datetime.datetime.strptime( "11/07/10 10:00", TF)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 308, in _strptime
    format_regex = _TimeRE_cache.compile(format)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 265, in compile
    return re_compile(self.pattern(format), IGNORECASE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'M' as group 5; was group 2
```

Now I believe my error is that I use %M twice when defining the date format.  Here's my query:

I would expect the code to either:

a) accept the fact you mine have the same time value twice in in a string (it might be redundent, but so is "monday" if you have the rest of the date) 
b) throw a value error saying that the same field shouldn't be used more than once.

This looks like something very different. What's going on?

Comment: It looks like an error telling you you're using the same field more than once. And it's telling you that the field is `'M'`, and it's telling you which groups you're trying to use it as. So it's option **b**.

Comment: If you look at the trace, you can see this is a side effect of the pattern being converted into a regexp which then fails. Since the strptime call handles other formatting errors by raising `ValueError` you can make a pretty decent argument the behaviour you are seeing is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

`Value Error` is used when "a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value" [<sup>(docs)</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) - so in that case, that would mean sending `TF` as a malformed string with a wrong formatting (try with `%K` for example).

Here you used a correct formatting - but as your error mentions, you failed on the the SRE paring part - since you defined the same group (that's how the `%x`s are interpreted) twice, and the regex parser failed since it can not understand when you tell him that the group `M` should match two different parts of the string, which it can't "guess" by itself.

Comment: The call doesn't have anything to do with regexen, that's an implementation detail - there's no reason it should leak out of the API and that API already returns `ValueError` for invalid formats.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing directly detected the specific error you made.

The datetime module turned your `strptime` format into a regular expression to do the actual parsing, without analyzing it (or having any need to analyze it) in sufficient detail to notice the duplicated field.  This resulted in an invalid regular expression, and the re module rightfully threw an error - one which I'd consider to be closer to a SyntaxError than a ValueError.  The datetime module passed this on without trying to figure out the source of the problem.

Comment: This call throws `ValueError` for bad formats so expecting `ValueError` is quite reasonable. There's code in there that looks like `raise ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'`  etc. All calls to `re.compile` are in try blocks and re-throw `ValueError`. They just didn't catch them all which you could sensibly complain is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 errors:

1. the format does not match because you are using "-" in TF and passed "/" as a time! you should pass the same format as the string.
2. you passed 2 minutes symbols ( 'M' = minutes, 'm' = months )

this is the correct solution for you:

```
import datetime

TF = "%d-%m-%y %H:%M"
last= datetime.datetime.strptime( "11-07-10 10:00", TF)
```

good luck!